# Guest Access to Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce communities

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

I have developed a Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce Community. In the Community Home page, I have used a Visualforce page. Within the VF page, it is rendering a Lightning App which have Lightning Component as dependency defined. All the component and app are having `implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="GLOBAL"` added.

Now this community is working fine when I am already logged-in to the Salesforce. With Guest, it is not rending the VF page. I have given the VF page into the guest profile(auto generated one). Any idea what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

[`forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes) only enables the component to be available in Community Builder.

In your scenario, you will need to use `ltng:allowGuestAccess` on your Lightning Out App to be able to allow the Guest Users access the component. [Share Lightning Out Apps with Non-Authenticated Users](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_public_apps.htm) discusses the implementation details.

> Add the `ltng:allowGuestAccess` interface to your Lightning Out dependency app to make it available to users without requiring them to authenticate with Salesforce.